# Session problems in Zope

Tags: session, session-variables, zope, beaker

The session data disappears when a page is duplicated a few times in Chrome/Firefox.

Below is an example:

Load http://www.example.com/parent/test. 
This page has a search feature which on click invokes a Python script that sets a session variable and redirects to a page template http://www.example.com/parent/redirected which accesses the session variable.

On http://www.example.com, from a dropdown menu "Test" is selected which leads the user to "http://www.example.com/parent/test" page.  On this page, once you hit search and immediately try to open another page on the website by "Opening in New tab", the original page does not load the results because the session is somehow empty now (`session.get('variable')` is empty) and hence "http://www.example.com/parent/redirected" does not load anything.

This seems to happen with Zope's built-in session manager and the effect is more pronounced when Beaker is used.

Comment: Does the browser send the `Cookie` header with the session key at all?

Comment: The Cookie header does have a "_ZopeId" in it which is the session key.

Comment: And that value doesn't change?

Comment: It doesnt change Martijn

Comment: So what happens then is that the browser requested another page before the transaction for the session id was committed. The second request won't find the id in the session database yet (be it in the ZODB or in a beaker backend) and assumes it is a new session instead.

Comment: You could experiment with a session manager based on [`itsdangerous`](http://pythonhosted.org/itsdangerous/), the way [Flask uses it](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/master/flask/sessions.py); then the cookie contains everything, there is no backend, no transactions. That's not a trivial task though; it requires you to write a new session manager for Zope.

Comment: But the problem is with the first request. Second request which is a new page loads fine. Opening of a new/second page is initiated while the search on the first page is processed.

Comment: Exactly, so the previous request hasn't completed yet, so the transaction is not yet committed.

Comment: But from what you said above, because transaction on the first page is not complete (which is the search process), the session id is not committed and hence the second request cannot find it. In this case, should not the second page fail to load or maybe create a new session?

Comment: You have a race condition here; the session being cleared because a new transaction created a new empty session as the previous transaction wasn't yet seen.

Comment: Thanks Martijn. I understand that although it required some effort from you to make me understand. So, are you saying that this is normal with Zope Session Manager or Beaker or is there a workaround without having to write a new session manager? I guess it is possible to do it by not setting session variable in python and by sending data to the template which can do a REQUEST.get()

Comment: The work-around is to not support opening new tabs during an ongoing request, really. You can minimize the chances by making sure your responses don't take a long time.

Comment: Also, this seems to be a consistent behaviour when done through New Tab. But if you keep the second page opened already, hit search on the first page and immediately reload the second page which should create a new session and the first page search should fail. But this ain't happening at all. I do not understand how the session copes differently with an already opened page and a page opened from within the search page.

Comment: You could instrument the session manager to see when commits are taking place, but I'm fairly sure that transaction ordering is the problem here.